# Crack linear congruential generator knowing every other word in sequence

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator, congruence

I need to crack one of the example of linear congruential generator.

I have $X_{n+1} = (a \cdot X_n + b) \bmod m$

and I know every other word in the output sequence:

..., 3158, ..., 1888, ..., 1285, ..., 1744, ..., 253, ..., 722, ...

The question is how to get the generator parameters ($a$, $b$, $m$) ?
I have read [Cracking a linear congruential generator](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator)
but still don't know how to break it.

Comment: Hint: compute $X_{n+2}$ as a function of $X_n$; suprises, that's a standard LCG with the same $m$, and you know consecutive output for it. From that find $a'$, $b'$, $m$ for that other LCG using a standard method, then from that derive $a$, $b$ of the original.

Comment: so i took a sequence: 3158, 1888, 1285, 1744, 253, 722 and compute like in http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator. 
i've got m = 28683
and then a = 34533, b = 85489
With this parameters i try to generate sequence but it is not the same as input:
[1888, 1285, 1744, 19375, 16657, 6739, 12148, 17449, 21976, 1834]
only first 3 items are right.
am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: @Gravian That value of `m` is wrong (or my implementation differs from that used to generate the sample numbers).  `:sat \s a b -> everyOther ((lcg s a b 28683)) == [3158,1888,1285,253,722:[16]]` yields `Unsatisfiable`.

Comment: @Gravian How could you have used said link to compute `m`?  The provided formula uses `s_{n+1} - s_n` and you only know every other `s_i` value, not two consecutive values.

Comment: @Gravian: hints: The algorithm you used (successfully I guess) can obtain a _multiple_ of the actual $m$. The right $m$ is likely not too much above the highest output available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, rather than do cool math, the easiest approach is brute force!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    enum { X0 = 3158, X1 = 1888, X2 = 1285, X3 = 1744, X4 = 253, X5 = 722,
           M_START = 3159 };
    for (int m = M_START; m < 10*M_START; ++m) {
        for (int a = 2; a < m; ++a)  {
            int c = X2 - ((X1 * a) % m);
            if (c < 0)
                c += m;
            int my_x2 = (X1 * a + c) % m;
            assert(my_x2 == X2);
            int my_x3 = (X2 * a + c) % m;
            int my_x4 = (X3 * a + c) % m;
            int my_x5 = (X4 * a + c) % m;
            if (my_x3 == X3 && my_x4 == X4 && my_x5 == X5) {
                printf ("m=%d, a=%d, c=%d\n", m, a, c);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code does an exhaustive search.  In less than a second, it spits out:

```
m=3187, a=2663, c=2627
m=6374, a=2663, c=2627
```

Now, this is for an LCG that just outputs the values you gave without any gaps.  But we can easily do a little math to work out that if $a^2 \mod m = 2663$, then $a = 1200$, the modular square root of 2663 (in Mathematica, `PowerMod[2663, 1/2, 3187]`).

Likewise, we can easily find $c$.  Thus, we find $m = 3187, a = 1200, c = 854$.

And thus the actual sequence (with odd-numbered items in bold) is 2679, **3158**, 1111, **1888**, 497, **1285**, 346, **1744**, 2982, **253**, 1689, **722**, 390, **365**, 2235, **2587**, 1116, **1514**, 1064, **2854**, …

But maybe you worry that I've used a $\mathrm{O}(n^2)$ algorithm?  What if $m$ were larger?  Well, I was just feeling lazy, that's all.  We can easily drop the complexity to something far less.  It just makes for slightly longer code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int modular_inverse(int a, int m)
{
    // Based on code from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_inverse#C
    int t, nt, r, nr, q, tmp;
    t = 0;  nt = 1;  r = m;  nr = a % m;
    while (nr != 0) {
        q = r/nr;
        tmp = nt;  nt = t - q*nt;  t = tmp;
        tmp = nr;  nr = r - q*nr;  r = tmp;
    }
    if (r > 1) return -1;
    if (t < 0) t += m;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    enum { X0 = 3158, X1 = 1888, X2 = 1285, X3 = 1744, X4 = 253, X5 = 722,
           M_START = 3159 };

    for (int m = M_START; m < 10*M_START; ++m) {
        int diff0 = (X1 - X0);  if (diff0 < 0) diff0 += m;
        int diff1 = (X2 - X1);  if (diff1 < 0) diff1 += m;
        int diff2 = (X3 - X2);  if (diff2 < 0) diff2 += m;
        int diff3 = (X4 - X3);  if (diff3 < 0) diff3 += m;
        int diff4 = (X5 - X4);  if (diff4 < 0) diff4 += m;

        // diff1 = a * diff0   =>   1/diff0 * diff1 = a
        int inv_diff0 = modular_inverse(diff0, m);
        if (inv_diff0 < 0) continue;
        int a = (diff1 * inv_diff0) % m;

        int my_diff1 = (a * diff0) % m;
        int my_diff2 = (a * diff1) % m;
        int my_diff3 = (a * diff2) % m;
        int my_diff4 = (a * diff3) % m;
        assert(my_diff1 == diff1);

        if (my_diff2 == diff2 && my_diff3 == diff3 && my_diff4 == diff4) {
            printf ("m=%d, a=%d\n", m, a);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This version spits out its answer essentially instantly, taking 0.001 seconds to run the program.

```
m=3187, a=2663
```

From here, we can then figure out $c$ and then proceed as above.

BTW, if you enjoy more of a challenge, feel free to check out [this question](/questions/20495/how-brittle-are-lcg-cracking-techniques) I asked a while back.